# Mass Explicit Binding Update in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am writing a WPF application and in it a few models.
Each model has an editor control with which I can view & edit objects of that model.

For example:

```
        <Label Content="{Binding ID}" />

        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Department}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TelephoneNumber}" />
        <xceed:ByteUpDown Value="{Binding AccessLevel1}" Maximum="64" />
        <xceed:ByteUpDown Value="{Binding AccessLevel2}" Maximum="64"/>
        <xceed:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding PIN}" />
        <xceed:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding KeyCode}" />
        <xceed:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding UserLimit}" />
```

Whenever I change a value it is updated in the model, which is great; but I also want too add a save/cancel behaviour:

On "Save", and only then, the data will be copied to the model,
and on "Cancel", the data will be reloaded from the model.

I am not sure how to accomplish it.

One way I thought of is marking all bindings w/ `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`, but it requires a large amount of boilerplate code to update the source and it can get a bit cumbersome, since some models have more than 20 editable properties.

Is there a better way of doing so?

**Edit:**
I thought maybe someone reading this in the future would like to have the solution I used.

Given `class Key`:

```
class Key
{
    private KeyViewModel viewModel;

    public KeyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new KeyViewModel(this);
            return viewModel;
        }
    }
    // -=-=- Lots & lots of properties -=-=- //
}

public class KeyViewModel : Key
{
    public Key Parent { get; set; }
    public KeyViewModel(Key parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        CopyFromModel();
    }
    public void CopyToModel()
    {
        Type t = typeof(Key);
        var props = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (var p in props)
        {                
            if (p.CanWrite)
                p.SetValue(Parent, p.GetValue(this));
        }
    }
    public void CopyFromModel()
    {
        Type t = typeof(Key);
        var props = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (var p in props)
        {
            if (p.CanWrite)
                p.SetValue(this, p.GetValue(Parent));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a wrapper object around your model and bind with that. Once you pressed Save, copy all the values to the model from that wrapper object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about not updating the `Model` (keep values at the `ViewModel` level) until 'Saved', and reloading values from the `Model` to the `ViewModel` when 'Canceled' ?

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate? Should I create another abstraction layer between the model and the view?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to keep it `View`/`Model`, you can also have a 'copy' of the model you're binding to at the `Model` level an load / save from the original. But having `Model`/`View`/`ViewModel` layers (`MVVM`) and doing this kind application behavior at the `VM` is certainly a better choice.

Comment: Thank you, I will write a ViewModel and use it.

Answer (score 0):

One other way of achieving this can be to keep and expose the temporary Model at your VM and bind UI with that.

Once user click Save, update the Actual Model with your Temporary Model values. If user clicks Cancel, just clear the temporary model values. Keep updating the temporary model with the actual selected model values. So your temporary model will act as a intermediate container of values.

Comment: guess @franssu suggested this to you in his comments